# vb.net how to create a variable to count entries going in as inserts and updates

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a mysql database and a gridview. Now I want to count my inserts and updates. It has been suggested to set up a variables to represent each element e.g. nUpdates and nInserts, but I am unsure on how to do this? Here is the code I am using

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 
Using dbSQL_cmd As New MySqlCommand() 
    student_id = DataGridView1.Item(i, 0).Value.ToString 
    name = DataGridView1.Item(i, 1).Value.ToString 
    age = DataGridView1.Item(i, 2).Value.ToString 
    adress = DataGridView1.Item(i, 3).Value.ToString.ToLower 
    dbSQL_query = "INSERT INTO student  VALUES  (?id, ?name, ?age, ?adress) " + 
           " on duplicate key update name=(name=?name, age=?age, adress=?adress)"
    With dbSQL_cmd
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", student_id)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", name)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("?age", age)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("?adress", adress)
        ' .Parameters.AddWithValue("?status", ?????)
        .CommandText = dbSQL_query 
        .Connection = SQLConnection 
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text 
    End With 
    dbSQL_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End Using 
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check the number of rows in the table before and after your insert/update loop. The difference between them is the number of rows you inserted.

You know how many items there are in your gridview. From your code, each one is either an insert or an update, so subtract the number of inserts you did (from that first step) from the number of items, and that is the number of rows you updated.